# Ruach haKodesh and Shekinah?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, ruach-hakodesh

What is the difference between Ruach haKodesh and Shekinah?

Is there a difference between the two concepts or are they exactly the same?

Comment: I don't know, but the concept of "Ruach haKodesh" can be quite revealing in the following passage in Yesha'yahu 63, for which I would appreciate what is the proper translation into English, וַיִּזְכֹּר יְמֵי-עוֹלָם, מֹשֶׁה עַמּוֹ; אַיֵּה הַמַּעֲלֵם מִיָּם, אֵת רֹעֵי צֹאנוֹ--אַיֵּה הַשָּׂם בְּקִרְבּוֹ, אֶת-רוּחַ קָדְשׁוֹ.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore I took out the line you added because it's a summary of an existing answer to this question, and it doesn't make the question clearer.

Comment: @ ba If someone asks "whats the difference between ..." and someone cites a source which says  "I dont know the difference", in other words "I dont know the answer to your question". Can that be put in as an answer?

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore [Yes](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4616/1569), but the answer given (at least in its current revision) isn't "I don't know." In any case it doesn't belong in the question, at least in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Shekinah is the Divine Presence - meaning how God reveals himself in this world, while as Ruach HaKodesh is divine state of a PERSON who can reach higher spirituality than general public.

Don't be confused and DO NOT translate Ruach HaKodesh as Holy Spirit to get something like 1/3 of the Trinity in Christianity.

Comment: Thank you for your wisedom, great answer, ....so is it not applicable to say that Ruach HaKodesh is somewhat like "buddhahood" in judaism?  Forgive me for my lack of knowledge and the comparison.

Comment: I don't know what exactly is buddahood.

Comment: so is Ruach HaKodesh a higher spirtual state of being similar to enlightenment?

Comment: something like that

Comment: so would you say that you have Ruach HaKodesh?

Comment: no, me personally not, but there are rabbis nowadays that I heard about that they possess this feature

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved by citing sources to support it.

Comment: Lee, I cannot give you source for what I said that's like general knowledge in rabbinic schools, I believe everybody agree with this definition.

Comment: Does the following passage in Yesha'yahu 63 support your definition of Ruach HaKodesh ("divine state of a PERSON who can reach higher spirituality than general public")? וַיִּזְכֹּר יְמֵי-עוֹלָם, מֹשֶׁה עַמּוֹ; אַיֵּה הַמַּעֲלֵם מִיָּם, אֵת רֹעֵי צֹאנוֹ--אַיֵּה הַשָּׂם בְּקִרְבּוֹ, אֶת-רוּחַ קָדְשׁוֹ.

Answer (score 0):

*Jewish Encyclopedia* ('[Ruach HaKodesh](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/7833-holy-spirit)') says:

> What the Bible calls "Spirit of Yhwh" and "Spirit of Elohim" is called in the Talmud and Midrash "Holy Spirit" ("Ruaḥ ha-Ḳodesh." never "Ruaḥ Ḳedoshah," as Hilgenfeld says, in "Ketzergesch." p. 237). Although the expression "Holy Spirit" occurs in Ps. li. 11 (LXX. πνεῦμα τὸ ἅγιον) and in Isa. lxiii. 10, 11, it had not yet the definite meaning which was attached to it in rabbinical literature: in the latter it is equivalent to theexpression "Spirit of the Lord," which was avoided on account of the disinclination to the use of the Tetragrammaton (see, for example, Targ. to Isa. xl. 13). It is probably owing to this fact that the Shekinah is often referred to instead of the Holy Spirit. It is said of the former, as of the Holy Spirit, that it rests upon a person.

Comment: "The difference between the two has not been determined." means: We, the writers of the *Jewish Encyclopedia*, don't know the difference.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34247)

Comment: @sabbahillel How does this not answer the question?

Comment: @ba The question is, what is the difference between two. This answer does not show the difference.