# What are clear and concise translations of the various meanings of "Ruach HaKodesh" in English?

Tags: hebrew, translation, nevua-prophecy, english, kedusha-holiness

The Wikipedia entry for "[Holy Spirit (Judaism)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Spirit_(Judaism))" identifies this English term with the Hebrew term *Ruach HaKodesh*<sup>1</sup>, but also indicates that *Ruach HaKodesh* can mean a higher spiritual state of an individual. I am looking for clear and concise English terms for the various meanings<sup>2</sup> of this phrase as it's used in Judaism.

---

<sup>1. Which also motivated this related question: "[Ruach haKodesh and Shekinah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50669/ruach-hakodesh-and-shekinah)"</sup>
<sup>2. If there are more meanings than the two I mentioned, please add those, too.</sup>

Comment: You could improve this question a great deal by [edit]ing in more information about where you've seen or heard this term in each of the senses you mention. Also, and maybe more importantly: If, in fact, the term has multiple meanings, why would it be desirable or possible to have one "best English translation"?

Comment: I've reopened this question per NBZ's edit and my subsequent one. The first half of the comment by @IsaacMoses remains true, though, IMO: you'd do well to include in the question more info on the meaning or context of the phrase as you understand it.

Comment: Note also that it's not literally "holy spirit": that'd be _ruach k'dosha_. More on that at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10164.

Comment: @msh210, WP (which I've edited into this post) certainly seems to make that identification. Not saying it's right, just that it's a valid premise for this question.

Comment: I, for one, have reversed my downvote on this question. I think it's in decent shape now.

Answer (score 6):

The English translation I've seen most for *Ruach HaKodesh* is "**Divine inspiration**." This translation is consistent with its usage in Jewish texts, as described concisely in [this Everything2 entry](http://everything2.com/title/Ruach+HaKodesh), to refer to a kind of sub-prophecy or Divinely-provided intuitive sense. This sense is consistent with the various uses of this concept in the Talmud, [cataloged](http://www.webshas.org/emunah/nevuah.htm) in [R' Gil Student](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/7533/gil-student)'s WebShas.

The word "inspiration," whose [sense of](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inspiration#Noun) "a person, object, or situation which quickens or stimulates an influence upon the intellect, emotions or creativity" apparently derives from its more basic meaning of "a single inhalation" via "a supernatural divine influence," fits nicely with the Hebrew *ruach*, which literally means "wind."